# Why can't I find macOS Sierra in the App Store?

Tags: mac-appstore, software-update, macos

On the Apple website, it says I *should* be able to find macOS Sierra on the App Store, on or after the 20th of September. However, when I open the App Store, it just looks like it did yesterday (no Sierra). I've even tried searching for it and switching to the US App Store (I'm in the UK.)

So why isn't it there? Is it meant to be, yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be available at 10 AM (PST - California time)

Comment: I'm assuming that 5:53 PM in England would be past that?

Comment: 10 AM PST would be 6 PM  GMT - or are you running a different time ??

Comment: Ohh, okay then - I'll wait then

Comment: Just for the record - I'm downloading right now from the App Store

Comment: How is this possible?

Comment: if you do a search on "Apple" then the first result is macOS Sierra